# XSLT 2.0 - Keep default element, remove duplicate siblings, filter unnecessary entries by attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

Using XSLT 2.0.

I need to filter all elements that have attribute `@xml:lang` where the attribute's values are not in a list of possible values I define. Ex allowable values: `x-default`,`en`,`en-US`,`en-GB`

When `@xml:lang` is detected on any element, and if `x-default` exists, then any sibling element of same type with `@xml:lang` value other than `x-default` should be compared to the element's text value of `x-default`, and if same element text value, be removed.
To say that another way, any sibling duplicates of `@xml:lang="x-default"` should be removed, based on the element's text value comparison.

Bonus points if it's possible to rank the order of duplicates, such that `x-default` is always chosen (if exists), followed by a second tier (`en`, `fr`, `ru`), followed by a third tier (`en-EN`, `en-GB`, `fr-FR`, `ru-RU`), where the second tier duplicates of the first tier are removed, and the third tier is compared to second tier (if exists), or else the first tier, so that the third tier is also removed if duplicate. This would need to be handled dynamically, as there are *many* possible languages.

A special case that should be also considered, is a situation where first tier (`x-default`) has `some value`, second tier (`en`) has `some valuation`, third tier (`en-US`) has `some value`. In this situation, there's no duplicate to remove, as the second tier exists and the third tier does not match it.

My current XSLT (doesn't attempt removing duplicates, as I've not found a sure-fire solution yet, and any attempts on my part have failed miserably). This is not my ideal XSLT, it's just the best I know to build currently, and it's able to filter down the data set. The programmer in me would like to see all the `or`'s changed to an array-value check so the values can be managed more cleanly, but I'm not sure if that's doable in XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="http://some.namespace/uri">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<!-- Select everything except comment/processing instruction nodes -->
<xsl:template match="attribute()|element()|text()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="attribute()|element()|text()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Remove categories & assignments not in our whitelist -->
<xsl:template match="//*[@category-id and not(@category-id='root'
    or @category-id='men' or @category-id='men_clothing' or @category-id='men_clothing_tshirts'
    or @category-id='sales' or @category-id='sales_men' or @category-id='sales_men_tees'
    or @category-id='sales' or @category-id='sales_women' or @category-id='sales_women_tanks-teeshirts'
    or @category-id='clothing' or @category-id='clothing_teeshirts'
    or @category-id='kids' or @category-id='kids_0816'
    or @category-id='men' or @category-id='men_shoes' or @category-id='men_shoes_skate'
    or @category-id='sales' or @category-id='sales_men' or @category-id='sales _men_shoes'
    )]"/>

<!-- Remove locales not default or in whitelist -->
<xsl:template match="//*[@xml:lang and not(@xml:lang='x-default' or @xml:lang='en' or @xml:lang='en-US' or @xml:lang='en-CA' or @xml:lang='en-GB' or @xml:lang='fr' or @xml:lang='fr-FR' or @xml:lang='ru' or @xml:lang='ru-RU')]"/>

<!-- Remove empty nodes -->
<xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space()) and not(.//@*)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example dataset below. In a real dataset, there are *many* more elements, so again the logic to remove duplicate `@xml:lang` entries must not be hard-coded to the XPath you might deduce, but rather operate on groups of same-type data, grouped adjacent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog xmlns="http://some.namespace/uri" catalog-id="catalog-products">
  <category category-id="sales_women">
    <display-name xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Women's Sales]]></display-name>
    <display-name xml:lang="en"><![CDATA[Sales for Women]]></display-name>
    <display-name xml:lang="en-US"><![CDATA[Women's Sales]]></display-name>
  </category>
  <product product-id="111111111">
    <display-name xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Aurora]]></display-name>
    <display-name xml:lang="de"><![CDATA[Aurora]]></display-name>
    <display-name xml:lang="en"><![CDATA[Aurora]]></display-name>
    <display-name xml:lang="en-US"><![CDATA[Aurora Fleece]]></display-name>
    <display-name xml:lang="es"><![CDATA[Aurora]]></display-name>
    <display-name xml:lang="fr"><![CDATA[Aurora]]></display-name>
    <display-name xml:lang="ru"><![CDATA[Aurora]]></display-name>
    <short-description xml:lang="de"><![CDATA[Aurora - Fleece-Top für Damen]]></short-description>
    <short-description xml:lang="en"><![CDATA[Aurora - Sweatshirt for women]]></short-description>
    <short-description xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Aurora - Sweatshirt for women]]></short-description>
    <short-description xml:lang="en-US"><![CDATA[Snow Fleece & Softshells - Aurora Fleece]]></short-description>
    <short-description xml:lang="es"><![CDATA[Aurora - Top polar de mujer]]></short-description>
    <short-description xml:lang="fr"><![CDATA[Aurora - haut en polaire femme]]></short-description>
    <short-description xml:lang="ru"><![CDATA[Свитшот SomeBrand для девушек]]></short-description>
    <long-description xml:lang="de"><![CDATA[<p class="productLongDescriptionTitle"></p><p class="productLongDescriptionSubTitle">Composition</p><p>100 % Polyester</p>]]></long-description>
    <long-description xml:lang="en"><![CDATA[<p class="productLongDescriptionTitle"></p><p class="productLongDescriptionSubTitle">Composition</p><p>100% Polyester</p>]]></long-description>
    <long-description xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[<p class="productLongDescriptionTitle"><p class="productLongDescriptionSubTitle">Composition</p><p>100% Polyester</p>]]></long-description>
    <long-description xml:lang="en-US"><![CDATA[<p class="productLongDescriptionTitle"></p><p>The stretchy, polar fleece Aurora zip-up shields you from the elements with street-savvy style to have you standing out on the slopes and the sidewalk. Designed with a tailored fit, tech details include zippered hand warmer pockets, a lyrca binding finish, a chest pocket, flatlock seams for smooth comfort, and ergonomic seams for support. Imported. 100% polyester polar fleece.</p><p class="productLongDescriptionSubTitle">Composition</p><p>100% Polyester
Polar Fleece</p>]]></long-description>
    <long-description xml:lang="es"><![CDATA[<p class="productLongDescriptionSubTitle">Composition</p><p>100% poliéster</p>]]></long-description>
    <long-description xml:lang="fr"><![CDATA[<p class="productLongDescriptionSubTitle">Composition</p><p>100 % polyester</p>]]></long-description>
    <long-description xml:lang="ru"><![CDATA[<p>Женский свитшот SomeBrand из зимней коллекции одежды 2014. Характеристики: влаговыводящая технология DRY-FLIGHT, эластичный флис из полиэстера (250 г), теплые карманы на молнии для ладошек.</p><p class="productLongDescriptionSubTitle"></p><p>100% полиэстер</p>]]></long-description>
    <!-- === PICTURES === -->
    <images>
      <image-group view-type="hi-res">
        <image path="catalog-products/all/default/hi-res/111111111_aurora,v_kpv0_frt1.jpg">
          <alt xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Aurora 111111111]]></alt>
          <title xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Aurora 111111111]]></title>
        </image>
        <image path="catalog-products/all/default/hi-res/111111111_aurora,v_kpv0_frt2.jpg">
          <alt xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Aurora 111111111]]></alt>
          <title xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Aurora 111111111]]></title>
        </image>
        <image path="catalog-products/all/default/hi-res/111111111_aurora,v_kpv0_bck1.jpg">
          <alt xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Aurora 111111111]]></alt>
          <title xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Aurora 111111111]]></title>
        </image>
      </image-group>
    </images>
  </product>
</catalog>
```

Ex desired dataset:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog xmlns="http://some.namespace/uri" catalog-id="catalog-products">
  <category category-id="sales_women">
    <display-name xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Women's Sales]]></display-name>
    <display-name xml:lang="en"><![CDATA[Sales for Women]]></display-name>
    <display-name xml:lang="en-US"><![CDATA[Women's Sales]]></display-name>
  </category>
  <product product-id="111111111">
    <display-name xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Aurora]]></display-name>
    <display-name xml:lang="en-US"><![CDATA[Aurora Fleece]]></display-name>
    <short-description xml:lang="de"><![CDATA[Aurora - Fleece-Top für Damen]]></short-description>
    <short-description xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Aurora - Sweatshirt for women]]></short-description>
    <short-description xml:lang="en-US"><![CDATA[Snow Fleece & Softshells - Aurora Fleece]]></short-description>
    <short-description xml:lang="es"><![CDATA[Aurora - Top polar de mujer]]></short-description>
    <short-description xml:lang="fr"><![CDATA[Aurora - haut en polaire femme]]></short-description>
    <short-description xml:lang="ru"><![CDATA[Свитшот SomeBrand для девушек]]></short-description>
    <long-description xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[<p class="productLongDescriptionTitle"><p class="productLongDescriptionSubTitle">Composition</p><p>100% Polyester</p>]]></long-description>
    <long-description xml:lang="en-US"><![CDATA[<p class="productLongDescriptionTitle"></p><p>The stretchy, polar fleece Aurora zip-up shields you from the elements with street-savvy style to have you standing out on the slopes and the sidewalk. Designed with a tailored fit, tech details include zippered hand warmer pockets, a lyrca binding finish, a chest pocket, flatlock seams for smooth comfort, and ergonomic seams for support. Imported. 100% polyester polar fleece.</p><p class="productLongDescriptionSubTitle">Composition</p><p>100% Polyester
Polar Fleece</p>]]></long-description>
    <long-description xml:lang="es"><![CDATA[<p class="productLongDescriptionSubTitle">Composition</p><p>100% poliéster</p>]]></long-description>
    <long-description xml:lang="ru"><![CDATA[<p>Женский свитшот SomeBrand из зимней коллекции одежды 2014. Характеристики: влаговыводящая технология DRY-FLIGHT, эластичный флис из полиэстера (250 г), теплые карманы на молнии для ладошек.</p><p class="productLongDescriptionSubTitle"></p><p>100% полиэстер</p>]]></long-description>
    <!-- === PICTURES === -->
    <images>
      <image-group view-type="hi-res">
        <image path="catalog-products/all/default/hi-res/111111111_aurora,v_kpv0_frt1.jpg">
          <alt xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Aurora 111111111]]></alt>
          <title xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Aurora 111111111]]></title>
        </image>
        <image path="catalog-products/all/default/hi-res/111111111_aurora,v_kpv0_frt2.jpg">
          <alt xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Aurora 111111111]]></alt>
          <title xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Aurora 111111111]]></title>
        </image>
        <image path="catalog-products/all/default/hi-res/111111111_aurora,v_kpv0_bck1.jpg">
          <alt xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Aurora 111111111]]></alt>
          <title xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Aurora 111111111]]></title>
        </image>
      </image-group>
    </images>
  </product>
</catalog>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "should be compared to the text of `x-default`? `x-default` is an attribute value already, do you mean the text content of the element `*[@xml:lang = 'x-default']`? What does your current XSLT code do?

Comment: Sorry, by text, I meant the text value of the element node. In the example above, look at the contents of the `display-name` and `long-description` elements, their text value is what needs comparison (using the rules I defined around `@xml:lang` attribute).

My current XSLT is currently focused on stripping unnecessary language nodes, but as I don't have a solid solution to remove duplicates currently, I'm leaving them as-is for now. I'll add my current XSLT above.

Comment: I've tried to clarify things a bit further above, let me know if still unclear

Comment: Why do you not keep `<display-name xml:lang="en-US"><![CDATA[Aurora Fleece]]></display-name>` in your expected output?

Comment: @MathiasMüller, sorry, you're correct that should remain. I'll update.

Comment: I've added a bounty of 50 pts

Comment: If I can make a suggestion: ask one question at a time. Minimizing the example to only what's necessary to demonstrate the (single) problem would be also beneficial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something you could use as your starting point. That is, I believe it satisfies your primary request:

> When @xml:lang is detected on any element, and if x-default exists,
>   then any sibling element of same type with @xml:lang value other than
>   x-default should be compared to the element's text value of x-default,
>   and if same element text value, be removed.

To state it more clearly, it removes any element that satisfies all of these three conditions:

1. it has an xml:lang attribute;
2. the xml:lang attribute is NOT "x-default";
3. the value of the element is equal to the value of a similarly-named,
   sibling element whose xml:lang attribute IS "x-default".

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="http://some.namespace/uri">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="ns1:display-name ns1:short-description ns1:long-description ns1:alt ns1:title"/>

<xsl:key name="default-sibling" match="*[@xml:lang='x-default']" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', local-name())" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@xml:lang!='x-default' and .=key('default-sibling', concat(generate-id(..), '|', local-name()))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input, the following **result** is obtained:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog xmlns="http://some.namespace/uri" catalog-id="catalog-products">
  <category category-id="sales_women">
    <display-name xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Women's Sales]]></display-name>
    <display-name xml:lang="en"><![CDATA[Sales for Women]]></display-name>
  </category>
  <product product-id="111111111">
    <display-name xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Aurora]]></display-name>
    <display-name xml:lang="en-US"><![CDATA[Aurora Fleece]]></display-name>
    <short-description xml:lang="de"><![CDATA[Aurora - Fleece-Top für Damen]]></short-description>
    <short-description xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Aurora - Sweatshirt for women]]></short-description>
    <short-description xml:lang="en-US"><![CDATA[Snow Fleece & Softshells - Aurora Fleece]]></short-description>
    <short-description xml:lang="es"><![CDATA[Aurora - Top polar de mujer]]></short-description>
    <short-description xml:lang="fr"><![CDATA[Aurora - haut en polaire femme]]></short-description>
    <short-description xml:lang="ru"><![CDATA[Свитшот SomeBrand для девушек]]></short-description>
    <long-description xml:lang="de"><![CDATA[<p class="productLongDescriptionTitle"></p><p class="productLongDescriptionSubTitle">Composition</p><p>100 % Polyester</p>]]></long-description>
    <long-description xml:lang="en"><![CDATA[<p class="productLongDescriptionTitle"></p><p class="productLongDescriptionSubTitle">Composition</p><p>100% Polyester</p>]]></long-description>
    <long-description xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[<p class="productLongDescriptionTitle"><p class="productLongDescriptionSubTitle">Composition</p><p>100% Polyester</p>]]></long-description>
    <long-description xml:lang="en-US"><![CDATA[<p class="productLongDescriptionTitle"></p><p>The stretchy, polar fleece Aurora zip-up shields you from the elements with street-savvy style to have you standing out on the slopes and the sidewalk. Designed with a tailored fit, tech details include zippered hand warmer pockets, a lyrca binding finish, a chest pocket, flatlock seams for smooth comfort, and ergonomic seams for support. Imported. 100% polyester polar fleece.</p><p class="productLongDescriptionSubTitle">Composition</p><p>100% Polyester
Polar Fleece</p>]]></long-description>
    <long-description xml:lang="es"><![CDATA[<p class="productLongDescriptionSubTitle">Composition</p><p>100% poliéster</p>]]></long-description>
    <long-description xml:lang="fr"><![CDATA[<p class="productLongDescriptionSubTitle">Composition</p><p>100 % polyester</p>]]></long-description>
    <long-description xml:lang="ru"><![CDATA[<p>Женский свитшот SomeBrand из зимней коллекции одежды 2014. Характеристики: влаговыводящая технология DRY-FLIGHT, эластичный флис из полиэстера (250 г), теплые карманы на молнии для ладошек.</p><p class="productLongDescriptionSubTitle"></p><p>100% полиэстер</p>]]></long-description>
<!-- === PICTURES === -->
    <images>
      <image-group view-type="hi-res">
        <image path="catalog-products/all/default/hi-res/111111111_aurora,v_kpv0_frt1.jpg">
          <alt xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Aurora 111111111]]></alt>
          <title xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Aurora 111111111]]></title>
        </image>
        <image path="catalog-products/all/default/hi-res/111111111_aurora,v_kpv0_frt2.jpg">
          <alt xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Aurora 111111111]]></alt>
          <title xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Aurora 111111111]]></title>
        </image>
        <image path="catalog-products/all/default/hi-res/111111111_aurora,v_kpv0_bck1.jpg">
          <alt xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Aurora 111111111]]></alt>
          <title xml:lang="x-default"><![CDATA[Aurora 111111111]]></title>
        </image>
      </image-group>
    </images>
  </product>
</catalog>
```

I believe you could extend the same principle to achieve your "bonus points" and the "special case" too (provided you can state the requirements as clearly as the one above - including mutual priorities). You *may* have to do more than one pass to get them all, though.

I suggest you ask a separate question (or search previous answers) regarding filtering based on a whitelist.

Comment: @JonL. Some reaction would be in order, I think - if only out of ordinary politeness.

Comment: My apologies, I hadn't been checking up on this, so didn't see notification that you'd submitted an answer.  Looks good, thanks.  Would love to find a solution for a lang hierarchy as I mentioned, but this is at least a start in the right direction. I'll pursue that another day

Comment: if you had used XSLT v2.0 as I noted in my question, would that have changed your answer here any?

Comment: @JonL. I don't think so.